# Tornado or node? what about express? node-django?

Tags: django, node.js, asynchronous, express, tornado

I'm a django developer but I want to continue learning other things, now asynchronous development.

I have been reading about node.js, I understood that it can be used with django and exists frameworks like express.js, so I don't know what to learn. Besides I read a bit about tornado because I'm better with python than javascript.

What do you advise me? tornado or node.js? another else? if node.js, should I learn it with django or it is better alone?

Which is more popular and has more libraries/documentations/jobs ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be helpful to your quest: http://mrjoes.github.io/2013/06/21/python-realtime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tornado` it's a good choice but I do not like the [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/documentation.html) another  one is `Twisted` this one has a good [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) I like so  much.

I'm also a `Django` developer and I like so much `Node.js` this one has a big `community` a lot of `documentation`  also has a very cool librarie for `WebSockets` `socket.io`  about `express` It's the backend of `MySpace` but I do not like so much `express`.

Combine `Django  and Node.js` It's not so hard but it's a quite  dangerous. I did a demo of how to combine them here you have the [github](https://github.com/Verurteilt/node-cud)

Comment: Thank you very much! So, do you advise me use Node.js alone instead with django? another framework for node.js or it is better pure node.js?

Comment: If You do not worry a lot about `security`   or you love `Django ` combine `Django and Node.js` but if you are the kind of people that want to try new things `I recommended you Node.js and express`